# REST API calls using Gatling tools

Tags: performance-testing, gatling

Actually am new to Gatling tool, just i want to make REST API using the Gatling tools.So any one suggest how to do and some related links about Gatling tool API calls.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

hi few example below for reference :-

```
          exec(
              http("Poll")
                .get(Configuration._URL + "/getData").check(status.is(200))
              )
```

or

```
        exec(
          http("Request")
            .put(Configuration.URL + "/createData").check(status.is(200))
            .body(("${xmlRequest}"))
           )
```

Comment: `.check(status.is(200))` can be removed as it's the default